# Running a daily script affecting the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to write a script that I can configure a **cron** to run every 24 hours beneath my **Rails** app.

**script.rb**

```
User.all.each do |user|
    days = user[:days]

    if days >= 1
        days = days - 1
    end

    user.update_attribute(:days, days)
end
```

However, whenever I run this, I get this error:

> uninitialized constant User (NameError)

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you are in Rails app's home directory, then simply:

```
rails runner -e production script.rb
```

For cron (suppose, script.rb is in home dir again):

1. Find out full path to your `bundle` (`which bundle`)
2. In your crontab add (change bundle and project paths accordingly):

   `0 * * * * cd /project_home && /bundle_executable exec rails runner -e production script.rb`

Comment: undefined local variable or method `script' for main:Object (NameError)

Comment: are you running `rails runner script.rb` from Project's home dir?

Comment: nope, from a subdirectory, i'll move things around.

Comment: now I'm getting a completely error, **fe_sendauth: no password supplied (PG::ConnectionBad)**

Comment: use `rails runner -e prodution script.rb` for production environment

Comment: Where is script.rb located? Place it in application's home dir

Comment: It's in the home directory. Running `rails runner -e production script.rb` and I get the error **fe_sendauth: no password supplied (PG::ConnectionBad)**

Comment: does "RAILS_ENV=production rails c" start?

Comment: It does indeed. Loads fine.

Comment: Try 1) "bundle exec rails runner ...," or 2) "RAILS_ENV=production rails runner ..."

Comment: Both return the same error: **fe_sendauth: no password supplied (PG::ConnectionBad)**

Comment: Take a look at your `config/database.yml`, is the production env's password something like `<%= ENV[DATABASE_PASSWORD] %>`?

Comment: It is indeed,  <%= ENV['APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

Comment: As @Aetherus find out, your problem is probably not having those environment variables defined when running script. So you should define them before running script. Please see this article for good consideration of it http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to `require_relative 'config/environment.rb'` (adjust paths to your use case) at the top of the script; There's a slight performance hit, but if you are only running this once a day, a few seconds of startup penalty won't matter.

Also, you may need to set `RAILS_ENV` appropriately to access the proper database tables.

Answer (score 0):

I always use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to manage my cron jobs.

Install `whenever`, then add the following script to your `config/schedule.rb`:

```
every :day do
  runner 'User.all.each {|user| user.decrement!(:days) if user.days > 0}'
end
```

Then run `whenever -w` from your terminal.